# Change Cursor in Visual studio addin

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, add-in

I am creating visual studio add-in. 
I want to change the mouse cursor to **wait** while my plugin is running and set earlier mouse pointer after it finishes execution.

How to change the **Cursor** ?

Answer (score 0):

Easy way :

```
// class for managing waiting cursor
public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    private Cursor previousCursor;

    public WaitCursor()
    {
        this.previousCursor = Mouse.OverrideCursor;

        Mouse.OverrideCursor = Cursors.Wait;
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Mouse.OverrideCursor = this.previousCursor;
    }

    #endregion IDisposable Members
}
```

and then, simply use

```
using (WaitCursor wait = new WaitCursor())
{
    // code that will execute with wait cursor
}
```